# What is the expected number of times 3 consecutive heads or tails will appear when flipping a coin 1000 times?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

If I take a coin and flip it 1000 times, what is the expected number of times I see a series of three heads or three tails in a row appear?

So for example the results: hhtttthhh contains 2 series of tails in a row (which overlap on the four tails) as well as one series of three heads in a row.

Comment: Try indicators.

Answer (score 0):

After any flip, the probability that the next two flips are the same is $\frac{1}{4}$.  Since $998$ flips are possible starts, the expectation is $\frac{998}{4}=249.5$.

Comment: This was also my initial intuition as well, but when I ran a python script to determine what the amount were it was 3 % some how which I found very unintuitive.

Comment: Python script error?  Programming error?